# idle load with mysql server - how to stop it

Tags: mysql, load

I am using Mysql Server 8.0.20 on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Once installed initially, it causes an idle load on my system.

But there are no users connected (none added) and no additional databases created after install, just default ones created at package install.

Now its just sitting there, causing a load:

How can I stop this? The load is ~1% and causes the CPU to wake from sleep.

I deactivated the perf. schema to no avail and there is no disc I/O.

Please view the pastbins below for detailed logs.

Thank you for your help,

fse

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: A) 16Gbyte RAM, 4 Cores, NVME to host the system and db
B) well I have to wait 24h for this one
C) to G) https://pastebin.com/u1FvXXK4

Also the power output for you:
https://pastebin.com/13crbupY

Comment: Also here is the install log: https://pastebin.com/XxfLfeXn

Comment: This is B) with some 20h uptime: https://pastebin.com/6SwPJ5n3

Comment: The uptime stored above has only 9,643 seconds.  Please repost about this time tomorrow.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime'; can be used to confirm seconds of uptime before picking up the data. Other data looks usable for workload analysis. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, here all queries after >24h uptime: https://pastebin.com/Fi0ahY8B Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Performance_Schema is ON in the data provided.
OFF would get you closer to true idle and 0 percentage used.
But then you would have less data available for troubleshooting timing troubles.

There were more than 10 Connections initiated.

There were 3 Flush_commands initiated.

With server_id = 1 - foundation for data replication could be active.

innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 would conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function, every SECOND.

innodb_io_capacity=30000  # from 200 to utilize more of your NVME IOPS capacity.

MySQL will still have to be prepared to take inbound activity.

For additional tips, view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to improve performance - when you have a BUSY server.

Comment: I tried 4 options above you mentioned, but the powertop output does not change. I set each option by itself and tried different values and combinations. Still, the high idle remains.

Comment: Please post powertop output so we can see what you are seeing when all the options mentioned are running.  Turning OFF Performance_Schema requires stop/start of MySQL after change your configuration to be effective.  Please describe high idle concept.